# Regex exactly 4 Letters 3 Digits any order

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a regex to get this cases:

Correct:
IUG4455
I4UG455
A4U345A

Wrong:
IUGG453
IIUG44555

need to be exactly 4 letters (in any order) and exactly 3 digits (in any order).

i tried use that expression

```
[A-Z]{3}\\d{4}
```

but it only accept start with letters (4) then digits (3).

Comment: Please elaborate on an example input and what your output needs to be (are you filtering an input to keep only those that match the 4 letter / 3 digit / any order constraint?). None of the 'correct' cases would match that specified constraint, but the first 'wrong' case would.

Comment: You need to use what's called a lookahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options for this:

**Option 1**: [See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DMOByL/1)

```
\b(?=(?:\d*[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:[A-Z]*\d){4})[A-Z\d]{7}\b
```

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?=(?:\d*[A-Z]){3})` Positive lookahead ensuring the following matches

  - `(?:\d*[A-Z]){3}` Match the following exactly 3 times

    - `\d*` Match any digit any number of times
    - `[A-Z]` Match any uppercase ASCII character
- `(?=(?:[A-Z]*\d){4})` Positive lookahead ensuring the following matches

  - `(?:[A-Z]*\d){4}` Match the following exactly 4 times

    - `[A-Z]*` Match any uppercase ASCII character any number of times
    - `\d` Match any digit
- `[A-Z\d]{7}` Match any digit or uppercase ASCII character exactly 7 times
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

If speed needs to be taken into consideration, you can expand the above option and use the following:

```
\b(?=\d*[A-Z]\d*[A-Z]\d*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*\d)[A-Z\d]{7}\b
```

**Option 2**: [See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DMOByL/2)

```
\b(?=(?:\d*[A-Z]){3}(?!\d*[A-Z]))(?=(?:[A-Z]*\d){4}(?![A-Z]*\d))[A-Z\d]+\b
```

Similar to Option 1, but uses negative lookahead to ensure an extra character (uppercase ASCII letter or digit) doesn't exist in the string.

Having two positive lookaheads back-to-back simulates an `and` such that it ensures both subpatterns are satisfied starting at that particular position. Since you have two conditions (3 uppercase ASCII letters and 4 digits), you should use two lookaheads.

Comment: Thank you, very  much that are exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative,

```
(?:(?<d>\d)|(?<c>[A-Z])){7}(?<-d>){3}(?<-c>){4}
```

doesn't require any lookarounds. It just matches seven letter-or-digits and then checks it found 3 digits and 4 letters.

Adjust the 3 and 4 to taste... your examples have 4 digits and 3 letters.

Also add word boundaries or anchors depending on whether you are trying to match whole words or a whole `string`.